# Memory almost filled by Android System and Google Application

Tags: insufficient-memory

I recently bought my first smartphone, a Sony Xperia T2 Ultra (D5303).
It has 8 Go of total memory space and I add a 16 Go SD Card.
Android System (5.1.1) takes 3.58 Go and Google/Android/Sony Applications take 4.19 Go.
There is less than 300 Mo of free space.
I always have a warning message that says that the memory is nearly full.

There is a lot of application that I never use (Google+, What's new, Docs), but I can't uninstall them nor move them to my SD card.

What can I do to have more free memory on the phone ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recommended approach without rooting:

1. Go to *Settings › Apps* and select the "All" tab
2. Pick the first "useless bloatware" in sight and tap its entry
3. Tap (in this order): Force-Stop, Clear Cache, Delete Data, Uninstall Updates (if any), Deactivate
4. Repeat for the other bloatware items.

What does this do?

- force-stop: make sure the app doesn't continue to run and create new data/cache
- clear cache: remove all cache files belonging to this app
- delete data: remove all user- and configuration data the app might have
- uninstall updates: if there are updates for system apps, those are installed in user-space. So removing them frees space you can use otherwise – plus is required if you want to …
- disable: make the app unavailable. Though you cannot uninstall system apps, you can deactivate most of them. This ensures they don't clutter your GUI (all the app's icons on your home screen and in the app drawer will be hidden), the app should no longer start automatically (and create new data/cache), plus it should not be updated anymore

This won't entirely cure the issue (you cannot e.g. regain the space those apps use on the system partition), but should ease the effects. At least some space can be gained this way.

A little warning: If unsure what an app is for, better do not apply the above steps on it. Though the system shouldn't allow you to disable essential apps, better be safe than sorry.

Comment: Thanks for this advice. I did it for some applications and it freed enough memory to make the warning message disappear.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a few tips:
 1. In **Settings**:**Apps**, you can move some applications to your SD card (Not all of them).
 2. You can also uninstall updates and clean data stored in the applications you don't use.

Comment: Uninstall updates is useless, because they automatically reinstall.

Comment: @Rodrigo not if you also disable them.

Comment: Disable them and your system becomes unstable in 3, 2, 1...

Answer (score 0):

You can root your phone and use applications like **Link 2 SD** to move apps to SD card, this will free up some memory.

Comment: And void your warranty, right?